Movie about Rocket Engineer
I've seen a movie a long time ago, and it was already an "old" movie.
I think between the 80s and 2000s.
It's the story of a man who built small rockets as a kid in his garden, then went to univertiy to became an engineer. He finally became a world-class rocket scientist. He ended up working at NASA.
He's also the father of the "classical" shape of the exhaust tuyere (hourglass-like).
I've memories of good and simple "semi-technical" scenes, where he explains how it works, and I'd like to watch it again.

*October Sky*? I've not seen it, and don't see the exhaust tuyere section, but the rest of it seems to fit.

Oh yeah, that's it ! Thanks ! BTW, the tuyere section is mentionned in the wiki page of the movie. It's called a De Laval Nozzle ;)

Fantastic, glad you found it. I've add this as an actual answer since it's confirmed.

October Sky
From the wiki:

October Sky is a 1999 American biographical film directed by Joe
  Johnston, starring Jake Gyllenhaal, Chris Cooper, Chris Owen, and
  Laura Dern. It is based on the true story of Homer H. Hickam, Jr., a
  coal miner's son who was inspired by the launch of Sputnik 1 in 1957
  to take up rocketry against his father's wishes, and who eventually
  became a NASA engineer.


The section about the exhaust (as you mention in the comments) is described on the wiki as well:

At the national science fair, Homer's display is received very well.
  Overnight, someone steals his de Laval nozzle, as well as his
  autographed picture of Wernher von Braun.




